# Collect total size with collectd df plugin

Tags: collectd

Is there a way to obtain total size of a device. Currently, I can get free, used, and reserved metrics but the total size of a device/file system doesn't seem to be available.

**Update 1**

The following aggregation pluin combinations were tried without required results:

- GroupBy Host+TypeInstance
- GroupBy Host+PluginInstance
- GroupBy    Host+PluginInstance+TypeInstance

Sample configuration:

```
<Plugin aggregation>
  <Aggregation>
  Plugin "df"
  Type "df_complex"

  SetPlugin "df"
  GroupBy "Host"
  GroupBy "TypeInstance"

  CalculateSum true
  </Aggregation>
</Plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at the aggregation plugin which might enable you to compute this

Comment: Aggregation plugin fails to produce total for each file system, for some reasons it ignores multiple GroupBy declarations.

Comment: I tried to reproduce, and I think you found a bug. Please file an issue on github